# Como fazer uma consulta por período dia, semana, mês no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, select, data, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como fazer uma consulta por período dia, semana, mês no MySQL?
por exemplo gostaria de exibir dados filtrados por períodos exemplo exibir dados ontem, semana passada, duas semanas, três semanas, um mês atras e assim por diante 
com a data no formato date **2017-06-21 09:26:31**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há muitas formas de fazer isso, veja a documentação do Mysql para Datas:[MYSQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

***Exemplos:***

*Ontem:*

```
Select * minhaTabela where Date(Data) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

ou

```
Select * minhaTabela where Date(DATE_ADD(Data,INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = CURDATE();
```

*Semana passada:*

```
Select * from minhaTabela where Week(data)+1 = Week(curdate());
```

...Na documentação tem várias funções e exemplos.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.